# Request scoped beans in SpringClientFactory AppContext's

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am using a `SpringClientFactory` to create a Ribbon client with a custom `com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient`.  This `RestClient` is wired with a `@Bean` that is request scoped (that is, `@Scope("request")`).  This is all done as a part of the Brixton release train.

```
RibbonClientSpecification customSpec = new RibbonClientSpecification("default.custom",
    new Class<?>[]{CustomConfig.class}); // defines custom RestClient
SpringClientFactory scf = new SpringClientFactory();
scf.setConfigurations(Arrays.asList(customSpec));
```

This `SpringClientFactory` has an `ApplicationContext` that it instantiates on its own for a given `name`, and this context doesn't have **any** Scopes registered with it.

I have a workaround that extends the `SpringClientFactory`, but it feels a bit clunky, and it makes assumptions regarding the type of `BeanFactory` that is available.

```
class ScopePropagatingSpringClientFactory extends SpringClientFactory {
    protected AnnotationConfigApplicationContext createContext(String name) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = super.createContext(name);

        ApplicationContext parentContext = context.getParent();
        if (parentContext != null) {
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory parentBF =
                (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) parentContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            String[] scopes = parentBF.getRegisteredScopeNames();
            for(String scope : scopes) {
                context.getBeanFactory().registerScope(scope, parentBF.getRegisteredScope(scope));
            }
        }

        return context;
    }
}
```

Has anyone tried using alternative bean scopes (request, session, globalsession) within a `SpringClientFactory`?

This one is more directed at the Spring Cloud maintainers: Is there a conscious reason that scopes are not propagated from the parent context to the ones created within the `NamedContextFactory`?  It seems like it might just be an oversight.

Comment: No one had ever tried creating a request scope bean. My question, is why do you want a request scoped `RestClient`?

Comment: Not a request scoped `RestClient`, but a `RestClient` that utilizes a request scoped bean.  The primary goal being to get access to parts of the request that came into this service, without having to pass the structure from call to call.  Ultimately, info from the request would be used to 'override' the ribbon setup to not call eureka in certain situations, but instead use a provided host.

Comment: Where are you doing this from, zuul or RestTemplate, or something else?

Comment: The `SpringClientFactory` is being used within a `RestTemplate`.  I will be doing something similar for Zuul, but that approach won't need the request scoped bean, as I should be able to get by with the `RequestContext` object Zuul has.

Comment: Spring has a thread local too. RequestAttributes or something similar.

Comment: Zuul should just route with a different filter.